# Referencing a component with full path fails in ColdFusion 2016

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

We are moving soon to ColdFusion 2016 from ColdFusion 10 and have noticed that we are getting some errors in our existing code base that we find confusing.

We have several components with methods that are expected to return a specific type. In versions of ColdFusion prior to 2016, we would specify the full path to the component containing the type in order to get it to work.

For example, this does **not** work in ColdFusion 2016:

```
public root.model.beans.MyObject function CreateMyObject()
{
    // blah blah...
}
```

Running the same code under ColdFusion 2016 produces the error `"The value returned from the CreateMyObject function is not of type root.model.beans.MyObject"` (it is).

This **does** work in ColdFusion 2016:

```
public MyObject function CreateMyObject()
{
    // blah blah...
}
```

The reverse is true in ColdFusion 10 - the first example works and the second doesn't.

My question is why is this? Is there some setting that controls this behavior? I am concerned about what the upshot will be when trying to reference components with the same name, but different paths. How can I differentiate between a component named Service.cfc found in /root/model/beans/ and one found in in /root/widget/api/?

I suppose we could change all the affected return types to "any", but why should we have to?

I'm sure I'm missing something really simple and would appreciate help in determining what it is. Thanks.

Comment: Is there an Application.mapping["root"] somewhere?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler, yes "root" is mapped in application.cfc.

Comment: Debug it by changing `root.model.beans.MyObject` to `any` and use `getMetaData` on the returned value in CF2016. It will tell you how the component was actually resolved (path).